# why is it bordercolour only appears to operate in chrome but not internet explore or firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

guys i am just trying to make a webpage with a simple border with a different colour to my background. when i load up the webpage in chrome it works fine the way i want it. but if i load the page in internet explore or firefox it doesnt show anything. how do i fix this for internet explore and firefox because i like the way it shows up in chrome (its exactly the way i want it in chrome).
heres my code

```
<html>
<body>
<table width="709" height="278" border="0" bordercolor="#000000">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use tables for layout. Don't use obsolete presentational attributes. Do use CSS. Browsers are rather more consistent when it comes to modern, standard markup and CSS.

Answer (score 6):

In your table, you have the `border="0"` - change that to represent the desired size of your border:

```
<table width="709" height="278" border="1" bordercolor="#000000">
```

Although, I would recommend using CSS to accomplish this:

```
table { border: 1px solid #000; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have border set to 0 so there shouldnt even be a border in chrome.

if you set it to

```
<html>
<body>
<table width="709" height="278" border="1" bordercolor="#000000">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

although inline styling isnt best so i suggest you go for the external CSS such as

```
table { border: 1px solid #000; }
```